# How to dynamically call methods within a class using method-name assignment to a variable

Tags: python

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def get(self):
        func_name = 'function' + self.i
        self.func_name() # <-- this does NOT work.

    def function1(self):
        pass # do something

    def function2(self):
        pass # do something
```

This gives the error: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

How would I go about doing this?

Note: `self.func_name` also does not work

Comment: Depending on your usage, you might be better off with either a list/dict of functions, or using a lambda function to pass an additional argument to the functions (the latter is mainly useful for callbacks).

Comment: This is not the code for which you got this error. when you do `self.func_name` you do not even access the local variable `func_name`. You are trying to access an instance variable named `class name` inside `self` - but such variable does not exist.

Comment: @Elazar yes my mistake. I was translating the code and missed this one.

Comment: There is a subtle difference between this question and question 3061. This question focuses on calling _methods within a class_. 3061 focuses on regular functions. Python newbies may not be a able to apply the answers that were written there to this situation.

Comment: Voted to reopen. I am said newbie and it's completely non-obvious to me how this is a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
def get(self):
      def func_not_found(): # just in case we dont have the function
         print 'No Function '+self.i+' Found!'
      func_name = 'function' + self.i
      func = getattr(self,func_name,func_not_found) 
      func() # <-- this should work!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Just for everyone's information, you can also give a default value to avoid exception. e.g., 'func = getattr(self, func_name, None)'. From python help (= help(getattr)): "When a default argument is given, it is returned when the attribute doesn't exist; without it, an exception is raised in that case."

Comment: How can I unittest it? I tried but When I assert the function call it gives me false

Answer (score 6):

Two things:

1. In line 8 use,

   func_name = 'function' + str(self.i)
2. Define a string to function mapping as,

   ```
     self.func_options = {'function1': self.function1,
                          'function2': self.function2
                          }
   ```
3. So it should look as:

   class MyClass:

   ```
   def __init__(self, i):
         self.i = i
         self.func_options = {'function1': self.function1,
                              'function2': self.function2
                              }
   def get(self):
         func_name = 'function' + str(self.i)
         func = self.func_options[func_name]
         func() # <-- this does NOT work.

   def function1(self):
         //do something

   def function2(self):
         //do something
   ```

Comment: this should work as well. but the getattr solution is a very clean solution that we all can use. Thanks again Sinhayash for this novel solution. It may be useful to solve some other related issue. thanks.